GraphQL iOS Swift Custom Scalar
I'm using GraphQL latest version 1.9.3 
They have removed option of passThroughCustomScalar
Currently response is coming in dictionary form and schema.graphql has generated as below
public typealias JSON = String
I've tried below code to convert string to dictionary
extension JSON: JSONDecodable, JSONEncodable {
    public init(jsonValue value: JSONValue) throws {
        switch value {
        case let string as String:
            self = string
        case let int as Int:
            self = String(int)
        case let dictionary as [String: Any]:
            guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: []) else { fallthrough }
            guard let serializedJson = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { fallthrough }
            self = serializedJson
        default:
            throw JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: value, to: String.self)
        }
    }
    
    public var jsonValue: JSONValue {
        return self
    }
}

Still I'm getting error of jsondecoding
ApolloAPI.JSONDecodingError.couldNotConvert(value: AnyHashable
 to: Swift.String))

Please help me

Does this answer your question? JSON Scalar throws JSONDecondingError.couldNotConvert in iOS apollo client

@LoVo no this answer does not relate to my question, because this link showing with run script and I've used Apollo with local package
